# Bigcommerce API for managing product videos

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a way to add videos to a product through the [v2 API](http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/products/videos) of Bigcommerce?
I am interested in using POST, PUT and DELETE methods for managing product videos through the API, similarly to the [API](http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/products/images) for the product images.

From what I have gathered the current API supports only the GET method for retrieving product videos, which have been already added to the product through the administration backend. Is there any other way to programmatically manage the product videos?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Best,

Kostas

Answer (score 0):

Create/Update/Delete is available for Product Videos now.

See: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/videos